# quick question about a definition of homeomorphism set classes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, equivalence-relations

Take $S$ a surface of general type. I want to define $Q$ the set of homeomorphism classes determined by the surface $S$. How can i define $Q$?
I think that $Q$ is determined by all surfaces $S^{'}$ sucht that there exist a homeomorphism $f:S \rightarrow S^{'}$. Am i right?

Comment: Why did you put the algebraic-geometry tag back in? How is this question related to algebraic geometry?

Comment: because i've found this in the proposition 5.2 of procceding of symposia n29 in pure mathematics at page 395. The proposition by Bombieri is related to Algebraic surfaces. My question is how $Q$ is defined?

Comment: here the proposition due to Bombieri: the set of homemomorphism classes determined by a complex surface $S$ where $S$ ranges over the isomorphism classes of surfaces with given $K^2>0$ and $\chi$ is finite

Comment: @GerryMyerson: just to confirm, this is definitely a question about algebraic geometry (albeit, one phrased in a maximally unclear way), One way to phrase it: it is (roughly speaking) asking how many homeomorphism types of real 4-manifolds with some fixed invariants are realised by *projective complex manifolds*.

Comment: yes but my problem is to understand what does Bombieri mean when he says set of homeomorphism classes determined by a surface $S$?

Comment: Dear Dario, my comment was just intended to reassure Gerry Myerson that the tag was correct. I do not intend to answer the question.